# executable jar from eclipse unable to use images within packages... sometimes

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, pdfclown

I have wrote a swing application and it works fine in eclipse but when I export it as a runnable jar parts of the application fail, when dealing with images, this line for example;

```
logo = getClass().getResource("/com/cogentautomation/logo.jpg").getPath();
```

eclipse is packaging the images in the com.cogentautomation package and I can see it in the `.jar` itself, I have tried both export methods, extract required libraries and package required libraries, one says;

```
FileNotFoundException com\cogentautomation\logo.jpg
```

the other says;

```
FileNotFoundException file:\c:\documents\hs.jar!\com\cogentautomation\logo.jpg
```

I am using a library to parse out a PDF file, which is where this error is occurring, however it works in eclipse and with other images that are on disk that aren't a java resource.

I've read other topics on the problem but nothing really seemed to help.

EDIT: addressing something in the comments, I require a `String` variable the library I am using requires a string input to read the image;

```
import org.pdfclown.documents.contents.entities.Image;

Image image = Image.get(logo);
```

Comment: Typically, you store the resources for a project outside the package definition. In a maven project, for example `src/main/java` is the code and `src/main/resources` is your assets

Comment: @cricket_007 i don't use maven.

Comment: Don't use 'getPath', instead just use the URL returned from 'getResource'

Comment: I said, for example. So you would just place the files in `src/` I believe, then they are bundled in the root of the JAR

Comment: @cricket_007 You'll probably find that every IDE has its own idea of where resources should be kept based on its internal build system, maven is just another build system with its own idea of where resources should be kept. So the op has identified that the images are in the jar, I think it's safe to assume the location of the resources (as far as the build process goes) is not the core problem

Comment: @MadProgrammer, i updated the original post to include why `getPath()` is required. though, that's no different to using a `toString()` method.

Comment: The issue will then come down to the pdf API to understand the String URL. Your only other choice is to extract the resource (possibly to a temporary file) and use that path

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am able to use that code in eclipse without `FileNotExceptions` being thrown. What is eclipse doing to allow the file to be used?

Comment: Having a look at the API, my guess is Image.get(String) is using Image.get(File), using the String as the argument for File, which won't work for URL (or a URL path), instead, you should use Image.get(InputStream) which would allow you to use Class#getResourceAsStream

Comment: @MadProgrammer `Image.get()` takes a proprietary `IInputStream` class, not `InputStream`.

Comment: You could generate a Buffer, writing the InputStream into something like a ByteArrayOutputStream

Comment: @MadProgrammer indeed, moments before you posted that I tried it and it worked. Thank you very much. Feel free to write an answer and ill mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the JavaDocs for [`org.pdfclown.documents.contents.entities.Image`](http://clown.sourceforge.net/docs/api/org/pdfclown/documents/contents/entities/Image.html) I "guess" the `Image.get(String)` is forwarding the call to `Image.get(File)` using the `String` as the parameter for the constructor of `File`

This isn't going to work for `URL` based paths.  Instead, you need to look towards `Image.get(IInputStream)` (why these APIs can't simply use what's already available :P)

So, digging through the API some more `IInputStream` leads to [`org.pdfclown.bytes.Buffer`](http://clown.sourceforge.net/docs/api/org/pdfclown/bytes/Buffer.html), not perfect, but it's a link.

You can use `Class#getStreamAsResource` and write this into a `ByteArrayOutputStream` which can then give you a `byte[]`, which can then pass to `Image.get(IInputStream)`